# ArrayFormula in google sheets SUM if values match criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas

Ok, so I've been stuck on this for a while now trying to create an array formula that will do the following:

Let's pretend the data I'm working with appears as such:

```
         SHEET 1                                     SHEET 2
   |   A  |   B  |   C  |   D   |  E   | F        |   A   |   B  |
 1 |  Up  | Down | Down |   Up  | Down |        1 |  Red  | $50  |
 2 |  Red | Green| White| Black | Blue |        2 | Green | $100 |
 3 |  $50 | $200 | $15  | Hidden|      |        3 | White | $10  |
 4 |      | $200 |      | Hidden| $100 |        4 | Black | $70  |
 5 |  $50 | $200 | $15  | Hidden|      |        5 | Blue  | $100 |
```

Using that data, I need a formula in column F (that I can copy and paste for subsequent cells in the column).

My actual sheet has about 45 columns across and about 25 rows down with sensitive financial information, so I'm using pretend data above on a smaller scale.

So the formula should look something like this (this would be posted in column F of Sheet 1). It needs to check if `$A$1:$E$1="Up"` (disregard anything that is not "Up") in addition, IF that array = "up" then check to make sure `$A3:$E3>$0` (I intend to exclude blank values and "hidden" values), then IF those 2 criteria are met, then return the corresponding value from `$A$2:$E$2` and use that as a search key in a lookup formula (HLookup, Vlookup, offset+match, etc). So for example, the Formula in F3 would match those 2 criteria (which would be `A2` [red] and then sum together all of the matching values - in this case, there is only 1 matching value, but usually there will be 3-5).

Attempt 1:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(OFFSET('Sheet 2'!$B$1,MATCH(IF(AND($A$1:$E$1="Up",$A3:$E3>"$0"),$A$2:$E$2,""),'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$A$5,0),0)))`

Attempt 2:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(AND($A$1:$E$1="Up",$A3:$E3>"$0"),OFFSET('Sheet 2'!$B$1,MATCH($A$2:$E$2,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$A$5,0),0),"")))`

My first attempt attempts to create an array for the Match search key that uses the IF statements to determine the results to be used in the match condition (In the example above, the only result would be "Red", but in the actual sheet, it could be an array like "Red, Blue, Yellow").

My second attempt attempts to first determine which cells we are using (based on IF conditions), then if the cell matches the IF then we will OFFSET the particular cell.

The errors I have noticed is that match doesn't seem to like my array in the search key. The first attempt results with an error saying it cannot find `"` in the range. (I guess I don't understand why it was searching for that...?). The 2nd attempt seems to fail because it uses the ENTIRE range ($A$2:$E$2), instead of only the cells that match the criteria.

I have tried such things as: VLookUp, HLookUp, LookUp (but it is not a sorted list). I've tried some other weird tactics, but non seem to give me what I need.

So far, the best I have come up with is:
`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF($A$1:$E$1="Up",IF($A3:$E3>"$0",0,OFFSET('Sheet 2'!$B$1,MATCH($A2:$E2,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$A$5,0),0)),0)))`

In my sheet, it found 3 cells that matched the criteria, but instead of adding Cell 1 value, Cell 2 value, and Cell 3 value, it just added Cell 1 value 3 times. So it seems it was only using `$A2` (the first option in the range for the match search key) and repeated it for every cell that matched.

I have also tried to include the Filter function (instead of IF) to eliminate cells that do not have "up" as their value (`$A$1:$E$1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$E$1="Up")*(VLOOKUP($A$2:$E$2,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE))*($A3:$E3>0)*(ISNUMBER($A3:$E3)))
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Except, there is 1 more factor that created a problem:

The range (A:E) width and the range (1:5) height on sheet 2 are the same, but they can be any number between 1 and 20 (so basically as small as (A:A, 1:1) and as large as (A:U, 1:20). I edited the formula to the exact number of current rows and your formula was perfect, but now I need to I guess calculate the amount of rows to use.

So basically, in sheet 2 find the FIRST blank row then subtract 1 to set the limit for the range (I do have data after the FIRST blank row that is not to be included)

Comment: The data after the first blank row are not numbers and it breaks the formula because it says "(my string) is not a number and cannot be coerced into a number"

Comment: Use a named range or table instead then.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Scott. I'm running into another issue. I thought the formula was working fine, but it does not seem to make any difference if `$A3:$E3>0` (I've tried other options, including changing some numbers to "hidden" and it seems to calculate everything that has "up" in `$A$1:$E$1` regardless of the value in A3:E3.

The named range worked great, btw. Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to work: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$E$1="Up")*(VLOOKUP($A$2:$E$2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE))*($A3:$E3<>"Hidden")*($A3:$E3<>""))`  having the `>0` was accepting "Hidden" as `>0`